# R: Convert text string to command

Tags: r, windows, variables, text, command

I need to find a way to make R "typing" a certain string of text when calling it in the console.

Let's say I have a list with many rows. Each row contains text representing calculation rules (in a format R could handle when reading it).

```
A <- 25
B <- 15
C <- 50
```

A, B and C are defined variables as shown above.

```
my_list <- data.frame(c("{A}+{B}<={C}","{B}={A}"))
```

My list contains some rules, which I want to print and check in one command.
By typing

```
my_list[1,]
```

I want to check, whether A + B is lower or equal to C indeed.

I search for a function which gives TRUE as a result.
Can anyone help?
Thanks for your support.
S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We remove the `{}` with `gsub` and then do an `eval(parse`

```
sapply(gsub("[{}]", "", my_list[[1]]), function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
# A+B<=C   B==A 
#   TRUE  FALSE
```

Here we assume that in the second comparison it is `B==A`

Answer (score 1):

```
require(glue)
require(magrittr)
A <- 25
B <- 15
C <- 50
c("{A}+{B}<={C}","{B}=={A}") %>% 
  sapply(evaluate, parent.frame())

#{A}+{B}<={C}     {B}=={A} 
#        TRUE        FALSE
```

Comment: This looks really good without having to change the OP's orignal string

Answer (score 0):

Could use `quote` right away and `eval` it E.g,

```
my_list <- c(quote(A+B<=C), quote(B==A))
eval(my_list[[1]])
```